# One-page AJAX-based WordPress site. How should I do it?

Tags: ajax, wordpress

I am trying to create a one-page WordPress website, something like the ones you sometimes see in ThemeForest's WP section: the whole website is a long page that has everything in one place, from about us, to portfolio, to some blog posts, to contacts.

Placing all things on one page is not difficult. But when I started thinking about how to present individual posts and pages, I realised that I probably need a general way of getting posts' data via AJAX, and create new blocks with JS. How should I go about this? I suppose this was done before, but I struggle to find something this specific on Codex or a tutorial with best practices.

Any advice or link will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a plugin such as jQuery Easytabs, [download it here](http://os.alfajango.com/easytabs/), that has a built-in Ajax component.

I've found that the easiest way is to just get all content to load into the divs ahead of time, vs. trying to load all pages through Ajax. However, appending something like '?ajax/ajax' to the end of your urls through the Easytabs plugin is one option that I have successfully used in the past.

If you decide to use the easytabs functionality, there is ample documentation on the page that I linked to.